How to skip a column in a Query method if a column does not exist in that table
Let's say we have a query like:
    @Query(value = "SELECT T.id FROM TrackingResultEntity T WHERE T.creationDate < :purgeBefore AND T.transactional = :transactional AND T.type = :type")

and this is in a parent repository which gets overridden by children repos, suppose for some reason I cannot use the "type" column for a specific children as it does not exist, How do I do that?
Thanks

Solution 1:
In the parent repository, make type optional by setting it to null if it’s not used.
Add a condition to include type in the WHERE clause only if it’s provided.
@Query(value = "SELECT T.id FROM TrackingResultEntity T WHERE T.creationDate < :purgeBefore AND T.transactional = :transactional" +
               " AND (:type IS NULL OR T.type = :type)")
List<Long> findTrackingResults(@Param("purgeBefore") Date purgeBefore,
                               @Param("transactional") boolean transactional,
                               @Param("type") String type);

In this approach:
If the type parameter is null (e.g., not set by the child repository), the WHERE clause ignores type, effectively not filtering by it.
If type is provided, it filters by type as usual.
Solution 2: Override the Query in the Child Repository
In the parent repository, define the query as usual.
In the child repository, override the method without the type parameter.
In Parent Repository:
@Query(value = "SELECT T.id FROM TrackingResultEntity T WHERE T.creationDate < :purgeBefore AND T.transactional = :transactional AND T.type = :type")
List<Long> findTrackingResults(@Param("purgeBefore") Date purgeBefore,
                               @Param("transactional") boolean transactional,
                               @Param("type") String type);
In Child Repository (without type):

@Query(value = "SELECT T.id FROM TrackingResultEntity T WHERE T.creationDate < :purgeBefore AND T.transactional = :transactional")
List<Long> findTrackingResults(@Param("purgeBefore") Date purgeBefore,
                               @Param("transactional") boolean transactional);

With this approach:
The child repository completely overrides the query, bypassing the need for the type column entirely.
https://admirable-smakager-729141.netlify.app/post/4

"make type optional by setting it to null" this wont work as the query being checked by the compiler. Also
